# MGWT and Firefox

Tags: firefox, gwt, mgwt

Recently I've wrote a simple mgwt app. It works differently depends on the browser (Chrome,mobile Chrome,mobile IE,Iceweasel  - under Debian) but works.

However, if I run my app on Firefox (22,38,mobile - under Debian) it's stuck. Buttons are not clickable, tabs don't work etc...briefly,it's not working properly under any Firefox.

Official showcase also don't work under firefox http://mobilegwt.appspot.com/platform/ (check it out by yourself).

I've tried changing user agent in gwt.xml (gecko,gecko1.8...) searched forums,groups,haven't found any similar question. 
So I'm asking here:
Is there any way to force mgwt to work under Firefox? 
If not, is there any good alternative? I'm thinking about refectoring it to pure gwt and make it as responsive as possible...

EDIT:

If anyone wondered. This branch fixes Firefox compatibility. 
https://github.com/jooink/mgwt